# Blank page after adding PHP code for drop down menu

Tags: php

When I add the following code for a drop down menu my page comes up completely blank. Not quite sure where the issue lies.

```
 <select name="isoID" id="isoID">

 <option value="">--Select--</option>
 <?php
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 
$list=mysql_query("select isoID, isotope FROM tbl_isotopes Order by isotope ASC");
    while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
?>
    <option value="<? echo $row_list['isoID']; ?>">
                   <? echo $row_list['isotope']; ?>          </option>
        <?
         }
         ?>
 </select>
```

I've been informed that PHP version 5.5.3 is installed on the server.

Comment: What browser renders it blank? Can you get the HTML that's being sent or received by the script?

Comment: Are short tags on? If not, change all `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: Fred -ii-  this is exactly what I needed to do. Thanks so much for that!

Comment: You're welcome Daniël. You may as well delete the question. Glad it worked out, *cheers*. Unless you insist on closing the question properly. The choice is yours.

Comment: You'll never see your die statement output, because it's inside a select tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you would like the question to be closed properly, therefore am submitting this answer as per my comment, should you wish to accept it and be marked as answered/solved.

If [**short tags**](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) are not set, then you will need to change all instances of `<?` to `<?php`.

On an added note, I must state though that you are using a deprecated MySQL function.

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.